# Multiform nested data

Tags: reactjs, django, web

Hey there i am trying to serialize the multiform nested data but i have tried everything but nothing works for me and also i did not get any kind of help from internet.

```
        # models.py
    from django.db import models
    from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
    from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
    from django.dispatch import receiver
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
    
    
    
    class Product(models.Model):
        CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
            ('clothing', 'Clothing'),
            ('electronics', 'Electronics'),
            ('books', 'Books'),
            # Add more categories as needed
        ]
        product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
        category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.product_name
    
        def inventory(self):
            return Inventory.objects.filter(product=self)
        
        def images(self):
            return Image.objects.filter(product=self)
    
        
    class Image(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
        img = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images", blank=True, null=True)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.img.name
        
            
    
    
    class Inventory(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='inventory')
        size = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    
        class Meta:
            unique_together = ('product', 'size', 'color')
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.product.product_name} - {self.size} - {self.color}"
    
    @receiver(pre_delete, sender=Product)
    def delete_images(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        Image.objects.filter(product=instance).delete()

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('img',)

class InventorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ['size', 'color', 'quantity']

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ImageSerializer(many=True)
    inventory = InventorySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'product_name', 'description', 'price', 'category', 'created_at', 'images', 'inventory')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        images_data = validated_data.pop('images', [])
        inventory_data = validated_data.pop('inventory', [])

        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for image_data in images_data:
            Image.objects.create(product=product, **image_data)

        for inventory_item_data in inventory_data:
            Inventory.objects.create(product=product, **inventory_item_data)

        return product
```

and i am getting data from frontend like that:
<QueryDict: {'product_name': ['aa'], 'category': ['electronics'], 'description': ['aaa'], 'price': ['12'], 'inventory': ['[{"size":"Small","color":"Black","quantity":"4"}]'], 'images': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Screenshot 2023-11-16 131611.png (image/png)>]}>

please give some solution

I have tried different libraries for parsing nested multiparse data but did not get a solution

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        images_data = request.FILES.getlist('images')
        inventory_data = request.data.get('inventory', [])
        inventory_data = json.loads(inventory_data)
        product_data = {
            key: value for key, value in request.data.items()
            if key not in ['images', 'inventory']
        }
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=product_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            product = serializer.save()

            for image_data in images_data:
                Image.objects.create(product=product, img=image_data)

            for inventory_item_data in inventory_data:

                Inventory.objects.create(
                    product=product,
                    size=inventory_item_data['size'],
                    color=inventory_item_data['color'],
                    quantity=inventory_item_data['quantity']
                )

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this is my view for saving data manually and this works but

```
# def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
#     serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
#     if serializer.is_valid():
#         serializer.save()
#         return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
#     return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this code not working.

Comment: Can you share your view source code? also, it don't seems your returning "serializer.data"  but your model queryset.

Comment: you do not need pre delete method f using cascade.
do you have any errors in response?

Comment: I have updated the code and add views in it please check that and tell me the solution if any.